# Simple form error messages appearing next to the form submission in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms, haml, simple-form

I'm working on a form, and I'm having a problem with the form submissions. If a user messes up or skips one of the entries, all of the error messages render at the top of the page. I'm wondering if I can get them to render next to each submission instead?

My controller looks like

```
def new
 @form_submission ||= FormSubmission.new
end

def create
 @form_submission = FormSubmission.new(form_submission_params)

 if @form_submission.save
   redirect_to thank_you_path
 else
   render :new
 end
end
```

With my view looking like

```
 .field
  = f.label :first_name, required: false, class: "font required-field"
 = f.text_field :first_name, :required => "", class: "stretch test"
```

and my CSS

```
.font{
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
 height: 15px;
}

.required-field::before{
content: ' *';
float: right;
color: red;
padding-left: 5px;
}

.test:valid{
  border: 1px solid #00aeef;
}

.test:invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each model is going to have an errors hash defined, made up of errors for each of the attributes of the model.  You can do something like `@form_submission.errors.full_messages_for(:first_name)` in your view to access the errors just for one attribute, in this instance the errors of the `first_name` attribute of the `@form_submission` model.

I typically create a partial for form errors, that looks something like this

```
<% unless errors.nil? %> 
  <div class="error-explanation">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <% errors.each do |error| %>
        <li><%= error %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then access it for each field in the form

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/form_error', locals: {errors: @form_submission.errors.full_messages_for(:body)} %>
```

Comment: I think that is an awesome solution!, however I keep finding myself getting an error message stated at `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You should use `@form_submission` as your local instead of `@post` @kdweber89.

Comment: Yes, I was using @post as an example but I'll update so that it applies to your configuration.

Comment: I really do apologize for not getting this work work, and I''m very grateful for your assistance, but as of right now. I took the partial that you created, and referenced it in my view. However if I attempt to submit a form with no entries nothing really happens.  In my console I see that I am getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: whichNavGetsTriggered is not defined`

Comment: Would it happen to be because i'm using `text_field` instead of `input`?

Comment: It would be difficult to know with the information provided. You may want to open a separate question or update your original post @kdweber89